# Solving a system of linear equations

Tags: math

I've been trying to solve a system of linear equations , but I didn't get this done. I hope getting an answer if it's solvable .

Say  we have an angle `A`   and this system :

```
y - x = sin(A)
x - z = sin(A+100) 
z - y = sin(A+200)
```

I'm looking for `x and  y and z , the value of the angle isn't constant, but it's known !
If there is a numerical way to solve it I'll be intressed .

PS: this NOT a homework.  and everything I've tried is written on papers that 's the reason I didn't put here.

Comment: Just to be clear: at the point when you want to solve this equation system, `A` is known? I.e. the only variables are `x,y,z` and not `A`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add all equations you get

> sin(A) + sin(A + 100) + sin(A + 200) = 0

So your system isn't solvable if the above sum is not zero. If it's zero then you have infinite solutions:

> x = x, y = x + sin(A), z = x - sin(A + 100)

where x can have any value.

Comment: First thank for your answer but I have to ask  there is a way i the summe of the sinus(a) +sin(a+100) ... isn't 0 to  adjust the x y z so that the system still fit ?

Comment: I'm going to put a new one, one moment please

Comment: @JunioCompressor here is better version of the question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588435/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-this-system-of-non-linear-equation?noredirect=1#comment47324335_29588435

Answer (score 1):

The system can be rearranged to

```
0       = sin(A) - sin(A+100) - sin(A+200)
x - z   = sin(A+100) 
- y + z = sin(A+200)
```

which means that there is no solution if `sin(A) - sin(A+100) - sin(A+200) != 0` holds. Otherwise, chose `y` at will and setting `x=sin(A+100)+y` and `z=sin(A)-y` yields a solution.