# Is there a way to adjust this system of non linear equation

Tags: c, math, mathematical-optimization

I've been to solve this problem for the last 2 days with no success.
say we have this system : 
    [image: system]

the has an infinite number of solutions when  :

[image: condition]

to get value of the angle Theta, I use this formula :

[image: solution]

The value that I get is correct but only in some points, because the system isn't solvable. 
and here is how it looks like :

[image: anlge]

the red curve represents the "must be" value and the blue one represents that I actually get.

after ploting the value of the sum :

[image: condition]

here is what I get :
[image: error]
as you can see it's  sinus curve, that seems to influence the "must be" value of the angle.

to simulate this I've been using this program :

```
      #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main (){
  float xin =0;
  float yin =0;
  float zin =0;
  float A =0;
  float B =0;
  float C =0;
  float angle =0;
  float outangle =0 ;
  float angledeg =0;
  while (angledeg <=(360*3)) {

    angle = angledeg * M_PI/180;
    xin = 0.11;
    yin = (sin(angle) / sqrt(3))  + xin;
    zin = (xin - (sin(angle +(120*M_PI/180))));
    A  = yin - xin;
    B  = xin - zin;
    C  = zin - yin;
    outangle = atan2((A*sqrt(3)) , (B -C) )   * 180/M_PI; // 100% correct 
    printf ("%lf \n" , outangle);
    angledeg++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So my QUESTION is : how could I use the value of sum to adjust the resulted value of "must be" value of the angle ( the red curve)

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this make a sense but it works : Removing sqrt(3)  :

```
yin = (sin(angle) / sqrt(3))  + xin;
```

I really don't get it, but it works fine ?  any idea why ?

Comment: Did you try using `double` instead of `float`? That will improve accuracy considerably.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary loss of accuracy, you should use `double` for all computations. The `%lf` is unspecified: use `%f` for `double` and `float` (`float` values are converted to `double` when passed to `printf`) or `%Ld` for `long double` values.

Comment: I've done it now but it didn't change the result

Comment: @Engine In your formula you use `A, B, C` but `A, B, C` are equations. How you put values in `A, B, C`?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor 1. thanks for your help  : A is equal to :y-x, and y is (sin(angle) / sqrt(3))  + x;

Comment: @Engine From my calculations `th = atan2(3 * A, B - C)` for `th` that the system has infinite solutions.

Comment: @Engine Also try: `outangle = acos((B - C - A) / 2) * 180 / M_PI + 120`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dramatically simplify the situation by considering that

```
sin(t)+sin(t+120°)+sin(t+240°)=0
```

which just means that the (weight) center point of any equilateral triangle on the unit circle is the origin.

Thus

```
sin(t)/sqrt(3)+sin(t+120°)+sin(t+240°)=sin(t)*(1/sqrt(3)-1)
```

So the only values of `t=theta` that make the system solvable are `t=0°` and `t=180°`.

---

In computing

```
y=x+sin(t)/sqrt(3); z=x-sin(t+120°)
```

you produce as value for C

```
z-y = - sin(t+120°) - sin(t)/sqrt(3)
```

and thus

```
B-C = 2*sin(t+120°) + sin(t)/sqrt(3)
    = -sin(t) + sqrt(3)*cos(t) + sin(t)/sqrt(3)
```

where in some kind of expectation you only expect the middle term, which is true for `sin(t)=0`, again for `t=0°` or `t=180°`.

Comment: I don't really get what do you mean  x isn't my angle ?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to avoid writing out theta, so used the letter x. Which is confusing due to its original use. Use now t.

Comment: I  know that the system is solvable only in 0 and 180° but , I want to get the correct angle from 0° tell 360° . it should be some kind of compensation and  my problem is how to do it

Comment: What and how are you trying to compensate? From the left sides you know that `A+B+C=0`, from the right sides you know that `sqrt(3)*A+B+C=0`, which implies 'A=0'.

Comment: the question how could I adjust the first calculation so that the blue curve fit on the red one ! since the  difference got some how  a sinus form and the sum of A+B+C  is also a sinus form, I hopping to combine the both to fit the blue to the red curve

Comment: This only happens if `y-x=sin(theta)`, without the `sqrt(3)`. But then the problem would be completely modified.

Comment: yes it wouldn't work  for the second formula with atan2

Comment: I really don't get it but it seem to work ! thanks for your hint, I'll be grateful for any explanation